# NHibernate Mapping from multiple tables

Tags: nhibernate

Consider the following table structure...

```
Appointment
-----------
ID integer
Description nvarchar
StatusID smallint

Status
------
ID smallint
DisplayText nvarchar
```

Now, for good or for evil, we want this situation to map to a class that looks like this

```
class Appointment
{  
    public int ID {g;s;}
    public string Description { g;s; }
    public string Status { g; private s; }
}
```

I.e. we want to pull the normalised status display text straight into the entity.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer is to create a Status entity and make the appointment class have a reference to that and map it in the normal way.

Comment: If you go this way you can use the component or one-to-one mappings

Answer (score 2):

Don't create an entity class.  Use an enum and EnumStringType as shown [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2006/03/14/140949.aspx).  This is exactly what you want I think.